# I have a collection of items. Based on the two data points, I need to query that items

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a collection of items. Based on the two data points, I need to filter out that items. As an example: I have a collection of action objects [{name: Detail}, {name: Spec}...] and I have two data points like I am category 'G' and in page 'A' would use only Detail action but I am category 'G' but in page 'B' only use Spec action and etc. What is the best OOP approach for this problem to scale to 100 of actions and base that on 10 of category and pages? I have tried to solved with Factory pattern but it did not work out.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to create mapping of pages and allowed actions for this page.
Example:

```
const actions = [{name: 'Detail'}, {name: 'Spec'}];

const pages = [
   { 
     name: 'A',
     allowedActions: [{name: 'Detail'}]
   },
   { 
     name: 'B',
     allowedActions: [{name: 'Spec'}]
   }
]

const getAllowedActions = pageName => {
  return pages.find(page => page.name == pageName).allowedActions;
}

console.log(getAllowedActions('A'));
```

Out:

> [ { name: 'Detail' } ]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but its missing category info, actions could be different based on the category. Like, there are n number of categories for each page.

Comment: Just add one more mapping for categories and actions.

Comment: You could do that, but that would mean a lot of code duplication, action object I have has 15 properties, I would think there is a better way to solve this problem

Comment: Code duplication is a little problem on your case. I propose you to do simple mapping and all will be ok.